# Maven set compiler source and target plus add manifest

Tags: java, maven, build

I'm trying to make my java program runnable using manifest in maven but at the same time I have to set the compiler source and target to 1.8.

My question is how do i compile those two?

So actually i have to combine these two builds:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> Build using compiler source and target

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Every `foos` tag takes multiple `foo` entries.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This really is probably a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>org.perfect.PerfectBot</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```xml
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

since these are the user properties for [`<source>` and `<target>`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) for the *compile* goal of the Maven Compiler plugin.